# No effect due to melt from pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to use the melt function in pandas. I copy-pasted the example code from GeeksForGeeks, yet somehow that isn't working on my jupyter notebook.

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# Creating the dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, 44, 1], 
                "B":[5, 2, 54, 3, 2], 
                "C":[20, 16, 7, 3, 8], 
                "D":[14, 3, 17, 2, 6]}) 
# function to unpivot the dataframe 
df.melt(id_vars =['A'], value_vars =['B']) 


# Print the dataframe 
df
```

[image]

Could it be because of some version problem?

Comment: You need to assign the result of `df.melt(id_vars =['A'], value_vars =['B']) ` to `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation `melt` does not occur `inplace` this means, the original `df` does not get automatically overwritten when you actually use the function. Therefore if you are in an interactive notebook and perform `df.melt()`, you will get the "melted" output. However if you then run `df`, you will **NOT** get the "melted" df returned because you never redefined your `df` as the melted dataframe. You must redefine or define a new variable as your melted dataframe. Hence:

```
# function to unpivot the dataframe 
melted_df = df.melt(id_vars =['A'], value_vars =['B']) 
# Print the original dataframe 
print(df) 
# Print the melted dataframe
print(melted_df)
```

Or, redifining your original dataframe:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars =['A'], value_vars =['B']) 
# Print the now melted dataframe 
df
```